# Unable to output all comments in a post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity

I want to output all the comments in a blog post. I have succeeded at entering all the data in the database and I can output the posts. However I cannot output the comments.

My Post model is as follows:

```
  public class Post
    {
        [Key]
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate{get;set;}
        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set;}

    }
```

My Comment model is as follows:

```
public int CommentId { get; set; }
public int PostId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PostId")]
public virtual Post Post{get; set;}
public string CommentCreateDate { get; set; }
public string CommentUpdateDate { get; set; }
public string CommeterName { get; set; }
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
public string CommentText { get; set; }
public bool Approved { get; set; }
```

My Action is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateComment(int ?id, CommentViewModel model)
{
    Post post = GetPost(id);
    var comment = new Comment();
    comment.Post = post;
    comment.CommentCreateDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    comment.CommeterName = model.Name;
    comment.EmailAddress = model.Email;
    comment.CommentText = model.Text;

    db.Comments.Add(comment);
    db.SaveChanges();

    m_commentList.Add(m_comment);

    ViewData["Comment"] = comment;
    ViewBag.Comment = comment;
    TempData["Comment"] = comment;

    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

My Index View is as follows:

```
@using Blog.Models

@{


    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    var viewDataComment = ViewData["Comment"] as Comment;
    var tempDataComment = TempData["Comment"] as Comment;


    bool isPreviousLinkVisible = ViewBag.IsPreviousLinkVisible ?? false;
    bool isNextLinkVisible = ViewBag.IsNextLinkVisible ?? false;
    bool isAdmin = ViewBag.IsAdmin ?? false;
}

@foreach (Post post in Model)
    {


        <div class="newsResult">

            <div class="title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Title)</div>
            <div class="updated"> <b>Created:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.CreatedDate) </div>
            <div class="updated"> <b>Updated:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.UpdateDate)</div>
            <div class="data"> <b></b>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Body)</div>


            @*<div class="data"> <b></b>  @Html.DisplayFor(x => tempDataComment.CommentText)</div>*@

            @foreach (Comment comment in  post.Comments.OrderBy(x => x.CommentCreateDate))  //Offending line
            {
                <div class="comment">
                    <div class="commentName">
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comment.EmailAddress))
                        {
                            <a href="mailto: @comment.EmailAddress;">@comment.CommeterName</a>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @comment.CommeterName;
                        }
                    </div>
                    said:
                    <div class="commentBody">@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(comment.CommentText).Replace("\n", "<br/>"))</div>
                    <div class="commentTime">at @comment.CommentCreateDate.ToString() on @comment.CommentCreateDate.ToString()</div>
                </div>
            }
```

Posts above are displayed no problem. However, when I try to access the comments it gives me an exception (The offending line is the beginning of second foreach):

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null
```

I Know for sure that the data has been created and that includes the comment which is otherwise available in a var `tempDataComment`.

Why is this happening? Can anybody help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this happening in the post or get ?? your post is just returning to index?

Comment: @Peru  it is happening in  the post. At index view of the post controller which is the view above. I want to list all the comments in that view.

Comment: Check the model which you pass to controller has value. I guess it is coming as NULL

Comment: @Peru but the model which I am passing to the PostController that is, CommentView model,  is not null, it has entered the data in the database and then it is available in var tempDataComment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by adding a check for nullity:

```
@if (post.Comments != null) //added this
            {
            foreach (Comment comment in post.Comments.OrderBy(x => x.CommentCreateDate))
            {

            <div class="comment">
                <div class="commentName">
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comment.EmailAddress))
                    {
                        <a href="mailto: @comment.EmailAddress;">@comment.CommeterName</a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @comment.CommeterName;
                    }
                </div>
                said:
                <div class="commentBody">@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(comment.CommentText).Replace("\n", "<br/>"))</div>
                <div class="commentTime">at @comment.CommentCreateDate.ToString() on @comment.CommentCreateDate.ToString()</div>
            </div>
            }
       }
```